# Bufferoverflow working with no breakpoints set, but not with a breakpoint set

Tags: c, gdb, buffer-overflow, buffer-overrun

I am developing a stack-based buffer overflow for a class. The entire payload is delivered through an environment variable due the nature of the application. This environment variable is set before the application is run.
My problem: My overflow works sometimes and does not work other times:

```
host@ubuntu:~/Documents/bufov$ gdb -q a.out
Reading symbols from /home/host/Documents/bufov/a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/host/Documents/bufov/a.out 
p=���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������^�1��F�F
  �
   ����V
        1ۉ�@̀�����/bin/sh 
process 12189 is executing new program: /bin/dash
$ exit
[Inferior 1 (process 12189) exited normally]
(gdb) q
```

It works fine as can be seend. However, if I right afterwards do the exact same thing, only adding a breakpoint and running through, I get an error:

```
host@ubuntu:~/Documents/bufov/level9$ gdb -q a.out
Reading symbols from /home/host/Documents/bufov/a.out...(no debugging symbols    found)...done.
(gdb) info file
Symbols from "/home/host/Documents/bufov/a.out".
Local exec file:
`/home/host/Documents/bufov/a.out', file type elf32-i386.
Entry point: 0x80484e0
....


(gdb) break *0x80484e0
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484e0
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/host/Documents/bufov/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, 0x080484e0 in _start ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.
p=���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������^�1��F�F
  �
   ����V
        1ۉ�@̀�����/bin/sh 
process 12195 is executing new program: /bin/dash
/bin/sh: symbol lookup error: /bin/sh: undefined symbol: __gmon_start__
[Inferior 1 (process 12195) exited with code 0177]
```

How come it does not work in my second run, and what is the error about?

Comment: Could you please show us some code?

Comment: in general if a program changes behavior under debug then its because you have unitialized data.

Comment: @ajay The code is trivial - it is a standard buffer overflow. The only difference is that the payload is read through an environment variable:  argument = getenv('payload'). I am sure that the address is overwritten correctly, but I am wondering how come the error displayed in my message occurs, simply because I set a breakpoint.